# IIS Express Url Rewrite Module very simple redirect not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, iis-express, url-rewrite-module

I want to redirect `index.php` to `home` in this snippet.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect index.php to home" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="index.php" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="home" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>      
  </system.webServer>
```

I have IIS Express 8.5 running. No redirect is happening for http://localhost/index.php, I get index.php and the same old 404. Tried deleting browser cache, didn't help. Any idea?

I don't have to do anything to enable the Url-Rewrite-Module, do I?

Comment: Use the IIS manager to create and test your redirect rules and check your access log file to see which URLs are generating 404 errors.

Comment: @Tim3880 this is IIS Express, IIS manager is only for the main IIS no? Wouldn't IIS manager also just generate rules like mine in the config file? I do not need to check which URLs are generating 404, this is a single URL that I'm trying to redirect, that's the one I'm testing and only getting 404 because the redirect is not working.

Comment: Some clarification - are you trying to redirect from `localhost/index.php` to `localhost/home` (and not just rewrite the URL)?

Comment: Can you check your website binding? sometime IIS does not like localhost. If not there, add localhost to your domain list

Comment: @Tim3880 he is using IISExpress, not IIS

Comment: Shouldn't your redirect URL be `localhost/home` then, and not just `home`?

Comment: @BrendanGreen tested it, didn't help.

Comment: And browsing to `localhost/home` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally found the problem. My ASP.NET MVC 5 project had two Web.configs:

- `/Web.config`
- `/Views/Web.config`

I had put the snippet above in `/Views/Web.config` by mistake, and it didn't work. Now I moved it to `/Web.config`, and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me.  Very frustrating and subtle mistake to make.